# CreateObject not working on user machine in VB6 for tlb file created in VS .Net 2010

Tags: .net, vb.net, dll, vb6

I am having this issue and I would appreciate if I can get any help to make it work. 
I am writing a DLL in .Net which I will use in VB6 project. For that matter every developer should be able to use this DLL in their VB6 projects by adding that DLL as a reference. So after researching I created a tlb file from .Net using intercom option. Below is my code for tlb file,

```
<ComClass(ComClass1.ClassId, ComClass1.InterfaceId, ComClass1.EventsId)> 
Public Class ComClass1 
#Region "COM GUIDs" 
    ' These  GUIDs provide the COM identity for this class 
    ' and its COM interfaces. If you change them, existing 
    ' clients will no longer be able to access the class. 
    Public Const ClassId As String = "7b640688-3583-46bd-9a69-26f8632864e3" 
    Public Const InterfaceId As String = "b3a59c91-fcd5-484e-83a9-24ec028e9b32" 
    Public Const EventsId As String = "1388246f-39c1-4b9b-bf6f-9dc3f1b75299" 
#End Region 
    ' A creatable COM class must have a Public Sub New() 
    ' with no parameters, otherwise, the class will not be 
    ' registered in the COM registry and cannot be created 
    ' via CreateObject. 
    Public Sub New() 
        MyBase.New() 
    End Sub 
    Public Function Multiplication(ByVal a As Double, ByVal b As Double) 
        Dim val As Double 
        val = a * b 
        Return val 
    End Function 
End Class
```

Now in vb6 project I have the following code on form load

```
Private Sub Form_Load() 
    Dim obj As ClassLibrary1.ComClass1 
    Set obj = New ClassLibrary1.ComClass1 
    MsgBox obj.Multiplication(2, 4) 
End Sub
```

So on my machine when I run this VB6 project it runs fine and and it displays 8 correctly. But on another machine which has VB6 installed, then we can correctly refer to this 'ClassLibrary1' and intellsense is working fine as well but when program runs it gives an error on the set statement that this activeX can't create an object.

I am absolutely clueless that why on earth this will not work.

Please forgive my ignorance as I am not an IT person, but I would really appreciate if someone can provide me a step by step instruction of how to resolve this.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have the appropriate .NET Framework installed on the other machine?

Comment: It appears that you have used the Interop Forms Toolkit template to create your VB.Net project.  I suspect that when you used regasm to register the library on the other machine that you did not use the "/codebase" switch.